# Iterating through two different references of firebase-database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database, in that at a particular node level there are dates and each date has key-value pairs with the value of certain numbers. Now I need to find the numbers which are common in the last 2 days.

I started by getting a snapshot of one date, then I wish to iterate for each value through the snapshot of the other date.

```
var numbers1 = firebase.database().ref('abc/def/'+date1);
var numbers2 = firebase.database().ref('abc/def/'+date2);
numbers1.on('value',function(snapshot) {

    numbers_day1 = snapshot.val();

});
```

Now, is this possible to pass the snapshot of date2 also along with it so that I can make an iterative function? Is it possible to add another event handler of date2 inside date1 event handler itself?

Database structure:

```
DATABASE
 [EMP
  [DATE1
   [KEY1
    [NUMBER1]
   ]
   [KEY2
    [NUMBER2]
   ]
  ]
  [DATE2
   [KEY1
    [NUMBER1]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

Similarly it goes on for more dates and numbers..

Comment: Could you share a snapshot or a visual representation of your database?

Comment: if you are question is if its possible or not , yes its possible .
but the listner will only be active once the numbers1 listner get executed once.

So baiscally there is a dependency , to fix this you can write both the listner outside and make  the numbers_day1/2 variable accessible to both

Answer (score 1):

Use Promise.all() method. like below

```
var numbers1 = firebase.database().ref('abc/def/'+date1).on('value');
var numbers2 = firebase.database().ref('abc/def/'+date2).on('value');
```

if you pass numbers1 and numbers2 to promise.all() method as they returning a promises. So the promise.all() method will wait for the two promises return the values.

for example

```
var numbers1Snap, numbers2Snap ;
Promise.all([numbers1,numbers2]).then(function(snaps){
    numbers1Snap = snaps[0]; // numbers1
    numbers2Snap = snaps[1]; // numbers2
    numbers1Snap.forEach(function(num){
        var num1Key  = num1Snap.key; //for example i'm matching keys to get the data
        numbers2Snap.forEach(function(num2Snap){
            var num2Key = num2Snap.key
            if(num1Key === num2Key){
               console.log("Matching Record " +num2Snap.val());
            }
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to use hash map features for Firebase snapshot? because what if i need two iterate similarly for 3 different dates? i.e common entries in 3 dates? to reduce the time complexity

Comment: I have added the database structure in the question

Comment: I hope it's possible.Do you know dates or otherwise you have iterate to them?

Comment: I know the value of dates, and i also know which dates i want to check

Comment: can you give sample data or update the question sample data. it would be better for me to tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a nicer and quicker solution, such as contracting the data in a way that both `number1` and `number2` are under the same snapshot. Structuring you data and using the indexes might be better than attempting the solution below.

But you did ask about iteration, you can try find one value and then search for the second one, something like:

```
var numbers1 = firebase.database().ref("abc/def/" + date1);
var numbers2 = firebase.database().ref("abc/def/" + date2);
numbers1.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(rowData) {
        numbers2.on("value", function(snapshot2) {
            snapshot2.forEach(function(rowData2) {
                console.log(rowData2 === rowData);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `var numbers1 = firebase.database().ref('abc/def/'+date1);`
`var numbers2 = firebase.database().ref('abc/def/'+date2);`
          `numbers1.on('value',function(snapshot) { `         
           `snapshot.forEach(function(rowData) {`
                `numbers2.on('value',function(snapshot2){`
                   `snapshot2.forEach(function(rowData2){...`
                  `});`
                `});`
          `});`

Will this work? The innermost function wrt snapshot2.forEach is not showing the same colour as other functions in the editor

Comment: I'll share the database structure too, but is it possible to use hashmap features to reduce the time complexity too?

Comment: I have added the database structure in the question